# Which dgemm call is the fastest?

Tags: fortran, lapack, blas

I need to do two matrix matrix multiplications to evaluate some intermediates:

[image]

I can do this using multiple variants of dgemms. The set I had until now uses one `'N','N'` multiplication and one `'T','N'` (N meaning normal, T meaning transformed):

```
       call dgemm('N','N',Pdim,Kdim,pqdim,           &
                 & 1.0d0,B,Pdim,D(1,1,iamthr),pqdim, &
                 & 0.0d0,Etilde(1,1,iamthr),Pdim     )

        call dgemm('T','N',pqdim,Kdim,Pdim,              &
                 & 1.0d0,B,Pdim,Etilde(1,1,iamthr),Pdim, &
                 & 0.0d0,E(1,1,iamthr),pqdim             )
```

Where `Pdim` is the dimension of P, `Kdim` is the dimension of K and `pqdim` is the dimension of pq and ij. `Kdim' is the smallest dimension, 'Pdim' is in from a couple hundred to maybe 2000 and pqdim can be everything from 1000 to 100000.

Now, I tried 3 versions of dgemm calls:

a) 'N','N' + 'N','N'

```
    call dgemm('N','N',Pdim,Kdim,pqdim,          &
             & 1.0d0,B,Pdim,D(1,1,iamthr),pqdim, &
             & 0.0d0,Etilde(1,1,iamthr),Pdim     )

    call dgemm('N','N',pqdim,Kdim,Pdim,                 &
             & 0.50d0,Bt,pqdim,Etilde(1,1,iamthr),Pdim, &
             & 0.0d0,E(1,1,iamthr),pqdim                )
```

b) 'T','N' + 'T','N'

```
    call dgemm('T','N',Pdim,Kdim,pqdim,            &
             & 1.0d0,Bt,pqdim,D(1,1,iamthr),pqdim, &
             & 0.0d0,Etilde(1,1,iamthr),Pdim       )

    call dgemm('T','N',Kdim,pqdim,Kdim,              &
             & 1.0d0,Etilde(1,1,iamthr),Pdim,B,Pdim, &
             & 0.0d0,E(1,1,iamthr),Kdim              )
```

c) 'N','N' + 'T','N' (see above)

I don't know why, but combination c) is the fastest. This does not make sense to me. In combination a) and b) I use pre-transformed matrices B (Bt) and the leading dimension of E is different of course.

It does not seem logical to me why c) should be fastest, because either `'N','N'` is faster than `'T','N'` or the other way around. Either way, a) or b) would have to be fastest.

So I'm left with a couple possibilities:

Either the compiler (ifort 19) notices two dgemms after one another and somehow magically concatenates them or since the dimensions are so vastly different that does make a huge difference. In the latter case I would still guess combination b) to be the fastest because there pqdim (the biggest dimension) is the leading dimension for both matrices...

Or maybe I just missed something essential?

Comment: If you run on NUMA data locality may be important.  We don't have visibility into how MKL divides work among threads.  Efficient cache usage in individual threads is important as well.  One choice may have nearly 50% larger cache footprint than another.  Public reference source for dgemm may give an idea but MKL doesn't use the same algorithm in all cases.

Comment: @tim18 I'm using OpenMP, but I'm parallelising a loop the dgemms are in. So the dgemms  themselves shouldn't run parralel.

Comment: @Fl.pf. They should not from your point of view, but did you make the steps to prevent them from running in parallel? Which exact LAPACK and BLAS implementation are you using? For example, I had to explicitly set the number of OpenBLAS threads to be 1.

Comment: @VladimirF MKL is used. MKL is threaded, mkl_get_dynamic() is true and OMP_GET_NESTED() is false. So I would guess that if nested OMP is false, the dgemm inside a parallelized loop should not be prallelized?

Comment: Hopefully......

Comment: In solution b) why did you change the dimensions K in DGEMM parameters M,N,K? Shouldn't it be `Kdim,pqdim,Pdim` rather than `Kdim,pqdim,Kdim`?

Comment: Since `B` is the biggest matrix and will dominate memory cost, we can focus on it and forget `D`  `Etilde` and `E`. Isn't it possible that `B` entirely fit in L2 cache? 1000*200*8bytes < 2Mbytes. In which case, performing the two operations using B, will be faster than loading another `Bt` from RAM to cache. That could explain why c) is better.